# EV range extension physics question

Tags: electromagnetism

Would it be feasible to extend the range of an EV using a generator?  I would guess that F=ma and perhaps a myriad of other factors would make a generator placed on an EV not work very well. I think of things like a wind generator to capture the wind power but the drag would slow the car down thus canceling the added energy. Or how about a generator in the rear wheels of the car to add back some of the loss?  I could imagine something like that working in a downhill scenario but i can't see it adding much if any in the whole driving scheme.  Seems Elon would have figured this out by now if any such thing would be feasible.  What you guys think?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please define EV.Do you mean Electric Vehicle?

Comment: Hybrids, where a generator that charges the batter is placed on the vehicle, work quite well. The balance of internal combustion vs battery is, of course, tuned differently. The BMW i3 has an option to include a small generator, hooked in only to the battery. So generators work just fine. But something like solar panels on the vehicle - not so much - there is not enough energy available to harvest to keep the vehicle running once the battery is depleted.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts